# Php response to browser instead of ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

If I have a php file that echoes data and I call it through a jquery ajax request, is there a way to print the data to the browser instead of the success callback function?

Comment: can you explain *why* you don't want to use the AJAX success callback?

Comment: add data as the first parameter to success function `success(data)`. now your response from the server should be in the javascript variable `data`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan nah i prefer to answer blindly, I think my answer is valid. the only way to get data is through the ajax callbacks

Comment: Nope there is no way.

Comment: @JasonJoslin read Erol comment please. It's that simple. (although probably not technically supercorrect since there *are* 'other' ways...)

Comment: Cool thanks @RokoC.Buljan. simple concise answers are the best answers, i get it.

Comment: @JasonJoslin :D OP already explained it all: *`instead of the success callback function`*

Comment: Yes, i can see i was too quick to answer without understanding the question. If you have a link to information about these 'other' ways I would be keen to learn. :)

Comment: Instead of AJAX you can create other data stream flows. Say websocket... webrtc... @JasonJoslin

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan, I've never used websockets before so im gonna do some reading on it. Thanks again